# Module Federation Next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to use the webpack and NextModule-federation to make my code as a microservice front-end.

Here it is my next.config.js

```
const { i18n } = require( './next-i18next.config' );
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const { NextFederationPlugin } = require("@module-federation/nextjs-mf");
const remotes = (isServer) => {
  const location = isServer ? "ssr" : "chunks";
  return {
    next1: `next1@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/${location}/remoteEntry.js`,
  };
};

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  webpack(config, options) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new NextFederationPlugin({
        name: "next2",
        filename: "static/chunks/remoteEntry.js",
        remotes: remotes(options.isServer),
        exposes: {
          "./button": "./components/Button.jsx",
        },
        extraOptions: {
          exposePages: true,
          automaticAsyncBoundary: true,
        },
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
  swcMinify: true,
  eslint: {
    // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has ESLint errors.
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
  i18n,
  env: {
    API_9000_USER: process.env.API_9000_USER,
    API_9002_USER: process.env.API_9002_USER,
    API_9004_USER: process.env.API_9004_USER,
    API_9005_USER: process.env.API_9005_USER,
    API_9006_USER: process.env.API_9006_USER,
    API_9007_USER: process.env.API_9007_USER,
    API_9008: process.env.API_9008,
    API_9009: process.env.API_9009,
    API_9000_SERVER: process.env.API_9000_SERVER,
    API_9002_SERVER: process.env.API_9002_SERVER,
    API_9004_SERVER: process.env.API_9004_SERVER,
    API_9005_SERVER: process.env.API_9005_SERVER,
    API_9006_SERVER: process.env.API_9006_SERVER,
    API_9007_SERVER: process.env.API_9007_SERVER,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

However, when I do yarn dev inside the folder next is not even creted the folder static and returns the following error

```
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
error Command failed with exit code 134.
```

Is there any suggestion? Thank you